# When trying to train the keras model, I get the error: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am preparing data from csv files in which training data and test data are stored in different files. My code is as follows:

```
pathAsk = 'ask.csv'
pathBid = 'bid.csv'
pathLabels = 'labels.csv'
types = [tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)] * 2500
types_label = [tf.int32]

datasetAsk = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(pathAsk, types , header=False, field_delim = ";")
datasetBid = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(pathBid, types , header=False, field_delim = ";")
datasetLabels = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(pathLabels, types_label, header=False)


def to_categorical(dataset):
    dataset = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(dataset, tf.int32), 6)
    return dataset

datasetLabels = datasetLabels.map(to_categorical)


def preprocessX(*fields):
    return tf.stack(fields[:2500])/5000 

train_ds = datasetAsk.map(preprocessX).batch(32)
label_ds = datasetLabels.batch(32)




inputs = keras.Input(shape=(2500), name="ask")
x = keras.layers.Embedding(1000, 64)
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=keras.activations.relu)(inputs)
x = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=keras.activations.relu)(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(6, activation=keras.activations.relu)(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(
    loss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics=['accuracy'],
    )
keras.utils.plot_model(model, "multi_input_and_output_model.png", show_shapes=True)

model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=label_ds, epochs=50)
```

My model throws an exception: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense / kernel: 0', 'dense / bias: 0', 'dense_1 / kernel: 0', 'dense_1 / bias: 0', 'dense_2 / kernel: 0 ',' dense_2 / bias: 0 '].

What do i need to do to start training a model? Thank`s for your help!

Comment: i think you are missing your labels in model.fit

Comment: The number of lines in the array of labels matches the number of training arrays. Perhaps the labels do not fall into the training cycle, tell me what the error is.